# Remove grid from PNG

Tags: gimp, png, image-editing, krita

I have several images like the one below. I need to remove the background grid using a Linux based tool (and I know *nothing* about graphic design!) Maybe this can be done with Gimp or Krita?

I could just painstakingly delete the grids manually but it's just too much work to do on ~20 images. Is there a way to this on at least a semi-automatic way?

[image]

Comment: Try something like (https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/),

Comment: I know a tool that can do it semi-automatically, but you have to purchase it. It is [PlotDigitizer Pro](http://plotdigitizer.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GIMP you could use the Select by Colour tool to select most of the grey coloured pixels, choose white as the foreground colour, then do Edit > Fill with FG color.  Unfortunately, this will also erase all the vertical grey lines on the blue dots too, plus you'll probably still need to do some manual retouching. If there had been some colour separation between the grid lines and all other lines, this might have been much easier.

Example using that technique

[image]

Sorry, but there's no magic "fix it" button in any raster software, not even using commercially available software like Photoshop.